# What causes the error in my custom module for OpenLayers 3?

Tags: 7, javascript

This error gives me a whitescreen with just this message:

```
Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginException: 
Plugin (ifplabel) instance class "Drupal\ifplabel\Plugin\Style\ifplabel\ifplabel" does not exist in Drupal\service_container\Plugin\ContainerAwarePluginManager::getPluginClass() 
(line 120 of /Users/me/Sites/ifp/html/sites/all/modules/service_container/src/Plugin/ContainerAwarePluginManager.php).
```

Background: The name of the module is called "ifplabel". I am making a custom module for OpenLayers 3 that will provide me with a custom marker style.

My Repo: https://github.com/joelhsmith/ifplabel

Comment: It would be easier to help if you posted the code from your custom module related to the OpenLayers plugin.

Comment: My repo: https://github.com/joelhsmith/ifplabel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In human language, the error I am getting means:

> I see that you have provided a module, but I can't discover it in the location you indicated.

It could not find it because I told Openlayers to look for a Plugin/Control, but my module was actually implementing a Plugin/Style, which means I gave it the wrong namespace.

I fixed it on commit 3bfabab in my github repo https://github.com/joelhsmith/ifplabel.

I hope this example module will help others who are trying to make a custom marker style.  It should work on any properly configured installation.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a mismatch between your annotation (the @ in the comment above your class) and your class declaration.

But you should post your code for more details.